# GNU Parallel --joblog logs only first line of commands inside a for loop

Tags: logs, gnu-parallel

I use GNU Parallel along a `for` loop like this:

```bash
for BAND in $(seq 1 "$BANDS") ;do
   # Do not extract, unscale and merge if the scaled map exists already!
   SCALED_MAP="era5_and_land_${VARIABLE}_${YEAR}_band_${BAND}_merged_scaled.nc"
   MERGED_MAP="era5_and_land_${VARIABLE}_${YEAR}_band_${BAND}_merged.nc"
   if [ ! -f "${SCALED_MAP+set}" ] ;then
       echo "log $LOG_FILE Action=Merge, Output=$MERGED_MAP, Pixel size=$OUTPUT_PIXEL_SIZE_X $OUTPUT_PIXEL_SIZE_Y, Timestamp=$(timestamp)"
       echo "gdalmerge_and_clean $VARIABLE $YEAR $BAND $OUTPUT_PIXEL_SIZE_X $OUTPUT_PIXEL_SIZE_Y"
   else
       echo "warning "Scaled map "$SCALED_MAP" exists already! Skipping merging.-""
   fi
done |parallel -j 20 --joblog "parallel.${JOB_CLUSTER_PROCESS}.log"
log "$LOG_FILE" "Action=Merge, End=$(timestamp)"
```

(for the records: where `${JOB_CLUSTER_PROCESS}"` a variable given by HTCondor).

In the logs I see only entries of the *first* command

```bash
echo "log $LOG_FILE Action=Merge, Output=$MERGED_MAP, Pixel >size=$OUTPUT_PIXEL_SIZE_X $OUTPUT_PIXEL_SIZE_Y, Timestamp=$(timestamp)"
```

which is actually a custom way to log actions during this loop in the following way:

```bash
# tell what you are doing
function log {
    echo "${@: 2}" 2>&1 >> "$1" ;
}
export -f log
```

Is it possible to get the second line

```bash
echo "gdalmerge_and_clean $VARIABLE $YEAR $BAND $OUTPUT_PIXEL_SIZE_X >$OUTPUT_PIXEL_SIZE_Y"
```

only or along with the first together included in the .log file created by `--joblog`?

Comment: I'm not sure how your code works (the parallel section, idw what the `log` section (at the end of your script) does ) But if you want only this line: `echo "gdalmerge_and_clean $VARIABLE $YEAR $BAND $OUTPUT_PIXEL_SIZE_X >$OUTPUT_PIXEL_SIZE_Y"` I think you can use:

Comment: Redirect the first line to stderr:  `echo "log $LOG_FILE Action=Merge, Output=$MERGED_MAP, Pixel size=$OUTPUT_PIXEL_SIZE_X $OUTPUT_PIXEL_SIZE_Y, Timestamp=$(timestamp)"` >&2

Comment: And after `done` (the end of the for loop) redirect stderr to.null or some file: `done > /dev/null` or `done > /path/to/somefile`

Comment: Thank you for the idea @EdgarMagallon. `log` is just a custom function that writes whatever is there in a custom `.log` file. I am exploring the use of `--joblog` and I realised that `--joblog` records only the first line.

Comment: Maybe it's a bit difficult to achieve what you want. (or maybe not, but given that I cannot understand the script completely, not sure how all is working). However, I think about piping `while read -r line; do `   after `done`, like this: 
`done |  while read -r line; do  parallel -j 20 --joblog "parallel.${JOB_CLUSTER_PROCESS}.log" ; done`

Comment: About `JOB_CLUSTER_PROCESS`, where do you assign it a value? It seems outside the for loop, if so, then the code about piping `while` would not make any sense.

Comment: Indeed, the `$JOB_CLUSTER_PROCESS` is passed to the script by HTCondor (actually `$CLUSTER` and `$PROCESS`, the composition of `$JOB_CLUSTER_PROCESS` is mine then), thus outside the loop.

Comment: I've seen a `--joblog` output, and the average `JobRuntime` for a custom `log` command is 0.241 seconds. Would I just put the log command right after the actual `gdalmerge_and_clean` command, would this be ok? The `$(timestamp)` in the `log` command would be _practically_ the same right? I am interested to know when a job starts.

Comment: I am asking something, hopefully, different enough so as to keep this question here short : https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/727389/13011.

Comment: Nice, I'll take a look! Hopefully someone or I can give an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--joblog` only adds to the joblog when the job is finished.

You are giving GNU Parallel two jobs:

```
log ...
gdalmerge_and_clean ...
```

`log` finishes fast and is added to joblog, but `gdalmerge_and_clean` probably takes longer to run.

I think you should consider rewriting your job as a function and call that:

```
doit() {
   BAND=$1
   # Do not extract, unscale and merge if the scaled map exists already!
   SCALED_MAP="era5_and_land_${VARIABLE}_${YEAR}_band_${BAND}_merged_scaled.nc"
   MERGED_MAP="era5_and_land_${VARIABLE}_${YEAR}_band_${BAND}_merged.nc"
   if [ ! -f "${SCALED_MAP+set}" ] ;then
       log $LOG_FILE Action=Merge, Output=$MERGED_MAP, Pixel size=$OUTPUT_PIXEL_SIZE_X $OUTPUT_PIXEL_SIZE_Y, Timestamp=$(timestamp)
       gdalmerge_and_clean $VARIABLE $YEAR $BAND $OUTPUT_PIXEL_SIZE_X $OUTPUT_PIXEL_SIZE_Y
   else
       warning "Scaled map "$SCALED_MAP" exists already! Skipping merging.-"
   fi
}
export -f doit

seq 1 "$BANDS" |
  parallel -j 20 --joblog "parallel.${JOB_CLUSTER_PROCESS}.log" doit {}
log "$LOG_FILE" "Action=Merge, End=$(timestamp)"
```

I recommend you try `--dry-run` if GNU Parallel does something you do not expect. It will tell you what commands it intends to run.

I think it will be time well spent if you read chapter 1+2 of GNU Parallel 2018 (https://www.lulu.com/shop/ole-tange/gnu-parallel-2018/paperback/product-23558902.html or download it at: https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1146014)

It should take you less than 20 minutes, and your command line will love you for it.

Comment: Indeed, I did this before reading this answer : put both in one function! Thank you for the explanations and recommendation. I am reading the suggested pages. Have read and did some of the exercises in the past. However, it's always useful to revisit the manuals. I completely forgot, for example the `--keep-order`! Mea culpa.-